# Apache2.4 Internal Server Error DirectoryMatch

Tags: .htaccess, server, internal-server-error

I'm trying to secure the .git and svn directories from anyone being able to access them because they contain sensitive meta information.

I've tried using the following rule but I'm receiving an internal server error and I'm not sure why:

```
<Directorymatch "^/(.*/)*\.(git|svn)/">
    Require all denied
</Directorymatch>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you have this directive?

Comment: In my .htaccess file located in the root public directory

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[As per Apache 2.4 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch), `DirectoryMatch` directive is not allowed in `.htaccess`

You can use `mod_rewrite` directives to do the same in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(git|svn)(/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thanks a lot, I didn't know it couldn't go directly in the .htaccess file.